# MAMP and Wordpress configuration

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I have installed MAMP for Windows on my pc that I've put in C:, and then downloaded Wordpress, now according to a video tutorial I'm supposed to see "My Website" in the MAMP start page from where I can be directed to localhost for the configuration. The problem is that I don't have "My web sites". What can I do?

Comment: 1) Please specify which OS you use MAMP (Windows or Mac) 2) Read the docs, they explain were the webroot is to be found, even where you can get it from the application itself 3) As with all PHP applications you should either place the folder containing the `index.php` inside the webroot or the entire application an create some kind of mapping to the public folder / index.php with  htaccess for example.